Can I simplify the following part of the query (google sheets)?
I have a list of conditions, which I have currently listed individually in the query.
Is there a possibility that the entire column can be read in in order to be more flexible in the future?
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$3;" AND D MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$3&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$4;" AND D MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$4&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$5;" AND D MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$5&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$6;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$6&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$7;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$7&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$8;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$8&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$9;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$9&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$10;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$10&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$11;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$11&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$M$19;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$12&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$M$20;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$13&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$14;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$14&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$15;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$15&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$16;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$16&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$17;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$17&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$18;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$18&"' ";"")

I had hoped that it would somehow be possible to simplify the whole thing as follows.
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$R$3:$R;" AND D MATCHES '"&ImportData!$S$3:$S&"' ";"")
&WENN($B$3=ImportData!$T$3:$T;" AND C MATCHES '"&ImportData!$U$3:$U&"' ";"")


The question mentions a query. Would you please edit the question to include the entire query, sample data and an example of the expected outcome.
